# Binary Expression tree, emptyStackException (java)

Tags: java, tree, expression, binary-tree

I have written a code which creates a binary expression tree from a given string expression:

```
public ExprIF buildExpressionTree(String s)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<s.length(); i++)
    {
        if(Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i)) || isOperator(s.charAt(i)))//containOp(s,i))
        {
            treeRoot = new Expr(s.charAt(i)); 
            stack.push(treeRoot);
        }           
        else if(s.charAt(i) == '(')
        {
            //do nothing
        }   
        else
        {
            rightSubTree = stack.pop();
            treeRoot = stack.pop();
            leftSubTree = stack.pop();
            treeRoot.setLeft(leftSubTree);
            treeRoot.setRight(rightSubTree);
            stack.push(treeRoot);
        }           
    }
    return stack.pop();
}
```

When I test it on the paper, it works well. The problem is this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.EmptyStackException
    at java.util.Stack.peek(Stack.java:102)
    at java.util.Stack.pop(Stack.java:84)
    at builder.TreeBuilder.buildExpressionTree(TreeBuilder.java:49)
    at builder.TreeBuilder.build(TreeBuilder.java:29)
    at Main.main(Main.java:12)
```

What is the reason for this error?

Comment: can you share sample input which you are using?

Comment: the operators are binary ones:*, +, -, /, ^, %  this method returns it sees that the given character is equal one of these binary operators

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is input string you are providing, it has spaces so third iteration of loop gets a space character and moves to last `else` statement. At this time stack is empty hence you get `StackEmptyException`. Try with **((1+2)*3)** input string.

In your logic you atleast have to have 3 elements (two digits and one operand) when last `else` is executed.

Another issue in your code is ')' closing braces are not considered so for input **"((1+2)*3)"** `else` statment will see following stack entries:

```
[1, +, 2]
[), *, 3]
```

You need to skip ')' as well, its better to write a method which checks for skip characters:

```
private boolean skip(char c)
    {
        return c==')' || c=='(' || c==' ';
    }
```

Now in `else if` change logic:

```
else if(skip(s.charAt(i))
        {
            //do nothing, its a skip character
        }
```

Comment: you are right, so I should have something like => else if(s.charAt(i) == '(' || s.charAt(i) == ' ') in my second else

Comment: yes, but better to move character skipping logic in a separate method, see edited answer above. If it solves your problem you can accept the answer.

Comment: Now my project is finished. But for testing, I've encountered another problem and that's when I get ( ( 1 + 2 ) * 3.5 ) => it gives me error of where I've got 3.5 => I know that the problem is reading character by character. can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

For the input you provided, your code simply forgot to deals with spaces.

Solution 1: add the following code to remove all spaces.

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\s", "");
```

Solution 2: replace

```
}

else
{
rightSubTree = stack.pop();
/* ... ... */
```

by

```
} else if (c == ')'){
    rightSubTree = stack.pop();
    /* ... ... */
```